# vagrant up slow creating Windows guest from Mac OS Sierra

Tags: vagrant

I'm getting started using vagrant and am testing things. I'm using a Windows 2012 R2 box based on evaluation provided by Microsoft (mwrock/Windows2012R2). This is what's in my vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "mwrock/Windows2012R2"
    config.vm.guest = :windows
    config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
    config.vm.boot_timeout = 300
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3389, host: 3389, id: 'rdp', auto_correct: true
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.gui = false
        vb.memory = 1024
    end
end
```

When I do vagrant up (I realize the first vagrant up is slow because it downloads the base box, I mean every time after that), it seems rather slow. Everything I read seems to indicate that it should take 25-30 seconds, but in my case it takes about 2.5 minutes. Anything that can be done to speed that up?

I'm running Mac OS Sierra on a MacBook Pro with a 2.2Ghz core i7 with 16GB of RAM.

Comment: Aren't Windows guests on Docker brand new though? How stable is that approach right now?

Comment: Not docker, using virtualbox through vagrant. @Rocket04